# How to connect to osgi framework (felix)

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I use apache felix and I want to connect osgi framework and to control it - in particularly to stop. By other words I have application A (osgi based) and application B. I want from B to connect to running A and stop osgi. I suppose felix must support interface via port. However, I can't find how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felix itself does not listen on any port. You need to install a bundle (or set of bundles) that offers the functionality that you need: That opens a port and accepts commands on some protocol. There are several micro-projects like that.

One that could work for you is Apache Felix Remote Shell: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-remote-shell.html